# A type that's easy to do arithmetic with and is guaranteed in bounds

Tags: haskell

Bear with me... this problem takes some explaining, but I think it's an interesting problem, and I assume others have faced it.

I would like to have a type that I *know* will always have a value between 0 and 1, inclusive.
That's easy enough to do, I can create a type `UnitInterval` and only expose my smart constructor, `toUnitInterval` and deconstructor `fromUnitInterval`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

-- | A number on the unit interval 0 to 1, inclusive.
newtype UnitInterval = UnitInterval Double
  deriving (Show, Eq, Ord, Fractional, Floating)

-- | Convert a value to a @UnitInterval@. The value will be capped to
--   the unit interval.
toUnitInterval :: Double -> UnitInterval
toUnitInterval = UnitInterval . max 0 . min 1

fromUnitInterval :: UnitInterval -> Double
fromUnitInterval (UnitInterval x) = x
```

So far so good. But users of my module will find that arithmetic with `UnitInterval`s and `Double`s is messy. For example,

```
λ> let a = toUnitInterval 0.5
λ> let b = 0.25 :: Double
λ> toUnitInterval $ (fromUnitInterval a) * b
UnitInterval 0.125
```

Of course I could make `UnitInterval` a derived instance of `Num`, so I can easily do arithmetic as long as I stick to `UnitInterval`s.

```
λ> a*a
UnitInterval 0.25
λ> a+a+a
UnitInterval 1.5 -- Oops! out of range
```

But I could write a custom implementation of `Num` for `UnitInterval`s, where operations like `+` do bounds checking.
But users of my module will need to do complex calculations where partial results won't be in range.
So they'll have to convert everything to `Double`s, do the calculation, and convert back to `UnitInterval`s at the end.

But wait... maybe there's a better way. I could make `UnitInterval` a functor!
An expression like `fmap (\x -> x * exp x) a` should give the result 
`UnitInterval 0.8243606353500641`.
Nice, clean code.
Now, `Functor` has the kind `(* → *)`, and `UnitInterval` has the kind `*`. 
But I can change that, like so...

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

-- | A number on the unit interval 0 to 1, inclusive.
newtype UnitInterval a = UnitInterval a
  deriving (Show, Eq, Ord, Num, Fractional, Floating)

-- | Convert a value to a @UnitInterval@. The value will be capped to
--   the unit interval.
toUnitInterval :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> UnitInterval a
toUnitInterval = UnitInterval . max 0 . min 1

fromUnitInterval :: UnitInterval a -> a
fromUnitInterval (UnitInterval x) = x

instance Functor UnitInterval  where
  fmap f (UnitInterval x) = toUnitInterval (f x) -- line 16
```

But that doesn't compile.
And in hindsight, I see that's because I would need to constrain the result of `fmap`,
which would give it a different type signature than the one in `Functor`.

```
amy.hs:16:29:
    No instance for (Num b) arising from a use of ‘toUnitInterval’
    Possible fix:
      add (Num b) to the context of
        the type signature for
          fmap ∷ (a → b) → UnitInterval a → UnitInterval b
    In the expression: toUnitInterval (f x)
    In an equation for ‘fmap’:
        fmap f (UnitInterval x) = toUnitInterval (f x)
    In the instance declaration for ‘Functor UnitInterval’
```

Sigh... back to the first version, with ugly arithmetic. Does anyone have a better solution?

Comment: why does it have to be `Functor`s `fmap`? - Why don't you just go with your definition (name it `imap` if you want ;) ) - if the function is useful for you go with it

Comment: You can't put extra constraints on the `fmap` implementation like that, what if I tried `fmap show`?  Strings don't implement `Num`, so it doesn't typecheck.  You could instead make a `UnitFunctor` class with a `ufmap` function that adds the `Ord` and `Num` constraints, that would work just fine.  It can't be a true `Functor` with the restrictions you want, but there's nothing stopping you from making a restricted `Functor`.

Comment: Yeah, creating my own version of `fmap` is a reasonable solution.

Answer (score 5):

You're going to face some difficulty with what you ask because the numbers on [0, 1] are not *closed* under the `(+)` operation. In other words, the "within [0, 1]" guarantee is not preserved by addition.

So there are a few ways to interpret what you want. One is that you could be looking for "phases" of operation between each you re-constrain the values to lie on [0, 1]

```
mapConstrain :: (Num a, Ord a) => (a -> a) -> (UnitInterval a -> UnitInterval a)
mapConstrain f (UnitInterval val) = UnitInterval (max 0 (min 1 (f val)))
```

Having operations like this alone will be constraining you will find as it is difficult to write something like

```
a :: UnitInterval Double
b :: UnitInterval Double
a + b
```

using `mapConstrain`. The `Applicative` typeclass suggests a mechanism for lifting this issue, however.

Another way forward would be to do constraining after every operation. Then we could instantiate `Num`

```
newtype UnitInterval a = UI a

constrain :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> a
constrain = max 0 . min 1

instance Num a => Num (UnitInterval a) where
  UI a + UI b = UI (constrain $ a + b)
  UI a * UI b = UI (constrain $ a * b) -- not technically needed!
  abs (UI a)  = UI a
  signum (UI a) = UI (signum a)
  ...
```

The final way forward is to allow for unbounded operations but only let users "view" `UnitInterval` values which are valid. This has perhaps the simplest implementation because you get to automatically derive `Num`

```
newtype UnitInterval a = UI a deriving Num

getUI :: (Num a, Ord a) => UnitInterval a -> Maybe a
getUI (UI a) = if (a <= 1 && a >= 0) then Just a else Nothing
```

Alternatively, you could just hit it with one final `constrain`. Of course, this mode of operation allows `UnitInterval` values to go outside of [0, 1] so long as they arrive back there before being viewed.

Answer (score 2):

When I think about numbers between zero and one, I tend to think about one of two things:

#### Rational numbers

```
data SM = SM {diff :: Natural, den :: Natural}

toRatio :: SM -> Ratio Natural
toRatio (SM diff den) = (1 + den + diff) / (1 + den)

instance Eq SM where
  SM diffx denx == SM diffy deny =
     diffx * (deny + 1) == diffy * (denx + 1)
```

Such numbers are truly guaranteed to lie in the correct range.

#### Computable real numbers

These are much more horrible, but there's a package out there for them. Roughly speaking, you can represent numbers between 0 and 1 as infinite streams of bits. Implementing multiplication will be an interesting challenge; if you somehow manage to figure out division, you won't have to worry about division by zero because it will simply run forever.